# How can I use NumPy to work with both colored and grayscale images?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, transpose, face-detection

I'm using face detection algorithm MTCNN which requires NumPy, and NumPy is throwing an error when I try to read a grayscale image. The error comes from calling NumPy's Transpose function with (0, 2, 1, 3) as axes when trying to work on a grayscale image. The same function is called with those same axes on colored images and they work just fine, it only breaks when the image is grayscale.

Here's a short of the code I'm using:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2

for filename in os.listdir("E:\\UTKFace"):
    name_path = "E:\\UTKFace\\" + filename
    pixels = pyplot.imread(name_path)
    faces = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
```

This works fine for colored images, but when the loop reaches a grayscale image I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-81451c75694c> in <module>
     55 
     56     # detect faces in the image
---> 57     faces = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
     58     if (len(faces)):
     59         count_positive = count_positive + 1

~\Anaconda3\envs\ambiente\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\mtcnn.py in detect_faces(self, img)
    306         # We pipe here each of the stages
    307         for stage in stages:
--> 308             result = stage(img, result[0], result[1])
    309 
    310         [total_boxes, points] = result

~\Anaconda3\envs\ambiente\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\mtcnn.py in __stage1(self, image, scales, stage_status)
    344 
    345             img_x = np.expand_dims(scaled_image, 0)
--> 346             img_y = np.transpose(img_x, (0, 2, 1, 3))
    347 
    348             out = self._pnet.predict(img_y)

<__array_function__ internals> in transpose(*args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\envs\ambiente\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in transpose(a, axes)
    651 
    652     
--> 653     return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
    654 
    655 

~\Anaconda3\envs\ambiente\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 
     57     try:
---> 58         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     59     except TypeError:
     60         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: axes don't match array
```

What are my options to circumvent this, besides removing all grayscale images from the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `axes` param in [numpy.transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

I suppose you have a `[N, H, W, c]` shape, representing `N` images of size `H x W` and `c` color channels. Then you would call `data.transpose([0, 2, 1, 3])` producing a `[N, W, H, c]` array. If you omit it will produce a `[c, W, H, N]` array, and if `N != c` it may break your program, otherwise it works but will give meaningless results.

Maybe your arrays are for gray scale images are of shape `[N, H, W]` instead of `[N, H, W, 1]`.

You can use `data.reshape(*data.shape[:3], -1])` or `data[:,:,:,None]` to make sure it has 4 dimensions.

If you have a `[N, H, W, 1]` array and you want to make it a `[N, H, W, 3]`
You can use `data.repeat(3, axis=3)`